# Shortcut is installed with the key name instead of the display name in InstallShield installer?

Tags: installshield

I create a shortcut in my project, pointing to a file called Help.exe. And I set its display name to "Help"

When installing it in Chinese(Simplified), it is OK and the shortcut name is "Help".

However, when set the display language to English and the format locale to Bulgarian, after installation, the shortcut name becomes "NewShortcut6", which is the key name instead of the display name.

Why?

Comment: I sense something to do with resource/MUI DLL or INIs. You sure that culture neutral or English specific ones are present?

Comment: @subdeveloper, Yes, If I install with English, then the shorcutname is also OK.